# How to guarantee the code mutual exclusive access in async method (no Monitor.Enter/Exit is allowed)

Tags: c#, database, monitor, usermanager

I have this function `PopulateUsers` called from c# Controller, that throws an exception "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code." - I have just found the reason on internet why - but need advice how to refactor my method so it is thread safe..
I am not supposed to call await function within the `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`.
But as you see in my code I am calling `await _userManager.CreateAsync(account)` and I have to `await` it - there is no sync version of the create function on user manager. I can take that code out of Monitor protection block but then how do I guarantee that the code is not going to be accessed from two different threads (two different user http calls)? I am also accessing database within the `Monitor.Enter/Exit` protection block.
How do I solve that? Any ideas?

```
private async Task PopulateUsers(string path)
{
    log.Info("UploadAccounts before locking");
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject);

    using (IDbContextTransaction transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            ... some code here
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(request.Dob, ConstantsDefined.DateTimeFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Account account = _context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == request.Email && x.DOB == dateTime);
            // Validate
            if (account == null)
            {
                // Account does not exist yet - create one
                // map model to new account object
                account = _mapper.Map<Account>(request);
                account.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
                account.Verified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                account.ScheduleGroup = group.ToString();

                // hash password
                account.PasswordHash = BC.HashPassword(request.Password);

                account.UserFunctions = new List<Entities.Function>();
                account.Schedules = new List<Schedule>();
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(account);
                Debug.Assert(result != null && IdentityResult.Success.Succeeded == result.Succeeded);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Error occurred.");
            log.Error(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Error occurred in Create:", ex);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
            log.Info("Create after locking");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One way is to use `SemaphoreSlim` which has async `WaitAsync` method. Instead of monitor. Which can be understood as an async equivalent of lock. That being said, why do you mix sync and async calls to the database? That defeats the purpose of async.

Comment: I will change to async all calls to the database. You are right.

Comment: The change to `SemaphoreSlim` will be much more complicated - its a massive change in my code.

Comment: If you don't mind you can wait on a _CreateAsync_ method, so it will be sync - just use _GetAwaiter().GetResult()_. Anyway, don't mix sync and async code, there is no benefit in that.

Comment: @janci how so? You literally just have to replace two monitor lines with two semaphoreslim lines. If that change is massive, then you're doomed.

Comment: I am relaying in my code on Monitor being re-entrant for the same thread - SemaphorSlim is locking second access by the same thread if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Monsieur Merso Thank you very much. With your solution I don't need to change Monitor to `SemaphorSlim`. My code stays the same. Lesson learned - don't mix sync/async code - thank you.

Comment: @janci I see. Well, IMO relying on reentrant locking is a sign of bad design or at least a red flag. Which you then try to solve with even worse design, i.e. using GetResult(), which may lead to deadlocks. Unless you actually properly turn all the async code into sync, which is fine.

Comment: @freakish Thank you. I will probably refactor my code to use SemaphoreSlim and remove re-entrant Monitor code.

Comment: What is the scenario? Are concurrent conflicting requests common? In that scenario do you want the second request to wait for the first to finish and then re-do whatever it is? Perhaps you could use EF's [optimistic concurrency check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#optimistic-concurrency). Then the result is that one request or the other fails. If the caller needs to they can retry and the second time it will succeed. You shouldn't have to use a lock. What if the app scales and two instances are running? Then a lock won't do anything.